# loading jquery ajax calls into divs without the page jumping

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm loading ALOT of ajax calls on a page, some of the ajax calls take longer to load than others and it means that sometimes the top ajax call has loaded when the user has already scrolled down the bottom of the page and so they won't get to see the data (unless they scroll to the top again)

here's my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#stage1').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage2').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage3').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage4').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage5').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage6').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage7').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage8').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage9').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage10').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage11').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage12').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage13').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage14').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
  $('#stage15').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890');
});
</script>
```

HTML

```
<div id='stage1'>
<div id='stage2'>
<div id='stage3'>
<div id='stage4'>
<div id='stage5'>
<div id='stage6'>
<div id='stage7'>
<div id='stage8'>
<div id='stage9'>
<div id='stage10'>
<div id='stage11'>
<div id='stage12'>
<div id='stage13'>
<div id='stage14'>
<div id='stage15'>
```

How can I make them load always at the bottom of the page? it doesn't matter which order they load in.

Comment: Try to use the .load() callback to append de #stageXX div when content is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your issue, use `load()` callback:

```
$('#stage1').load('myscript.php?data=1234567890',function(){$('body').append(this);});
```

Do that for all elements or if all elements have same targeted url in `load()` method, use a class.

Comment: thanks but i couldn't get this to work it didnt seem to do anything

Comment: it should work, check your console you could have some typo. BTW, just telling "it didnt seem to do anything" doesn't help much...

Comment: sorry! my bad i was using php to write the javascript and it was dropping the {} it's working perfectly now! thanks for your help!